# Angular MatTreeView getElementsByClassName not finding

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a MatTreeView generating a nice TreeView for a navigation side menu.

Once the page is loaded the plan is to expand the relevant page's node (along with all the parent nodes).

There may be multiple instances of the main page instances in the nav menu as there are 
different levels of detail on the main page and this is reflected in the nav tree.

Therefore I have dynamically loaded the page detail into the class which should allow me to create an array of items with getElementsByClassName and then pass them to my expandNode function.

But using getElementsByClassName is yielding no results.

Below is my code:

Template:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource1" [treeControl]="treeControl1">
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding class="pageID{{node.item_text_link | SpaceToUnderscore }}">
          <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
          <a *ngIf="node.page_id>1" href="page/{{node.page_id}}">
              {{node.name}}
          </a>
          <div *ngIf="node.page_id<=1">
              {{node.name}}
          </div>
        </mat-tree-node>
...
...
...
</mat-tree>
```

Controller:

```
expandNode(NodeId)
  {
      let pid = "pageID" + NodeId;
      console.log("Expanding nodes for: " + pid);
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName(pid);
      console.log(x); <------ THIS IS EMPTY
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, function(el) {
          console.log(el);
      this.customTreeControl.expandParents(el);
    });
  }
```

Via the inspector I know the classes are there and correct (including spelling).

I have tried running the expandNode method in the subscribe function which collects the data for the tree nodes and sets it to the dataSource so I know its not calling it to soon. I have also added a button to run this function once all is loaded and left for a while so there is no load latency and its still not finding these classes.

Copy and pasting the required class name into the inspectors find function finds it once I open the relevant element.

Why are the elements not visible with getElementsByClassName?

Are they hidden when TreeMatView isn't expanded?

Edit:
This is just the proposed way of doing this. If there is a better method of expanding a node and it’s parents by a reference to some data in that node eg a class name. It would be great. 
Bear in mind there may be multiple nodes with this reference. 
I am passing the data into the component from another component. 
E.g.
If I’m passing the page data ‘Flower’ (the main page is about Flowers)
I want all nodes (and their parents) which are relevant to ‘Flower’ to expand. 
I used the idea of having a class name pageIdFlower.
Make an array and process accordingly.

Thank you,

Comment: it is not correct (from angular aspect) to use document.getElementsByClassName, that is what i can tell, before i got clear understanding of your question

Comment: please - if you can simplify the formulation of the question

Comment: Updated with more explanation in edit

Comment: here is example on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/angular/vbmmvmrybrb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-dynamic-example.ts - is this solves what you need?